# Using v-if with a computed property which fetches a value in the Vuex store is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vuex-modules

So I'm currently working on a Vue/Nuxt application and I'm trying to make it possible to switch from mobile to desktop and have certain elements appear using v-if. I've got the v-if currently in this component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Search />
        <div v-if="device" class="header__mobile-menu-toggle">
            <a @click="$emit('openMobileMenu', $event)" href="#" title="Open menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div v-if="device" class="header__mobile-menu-close">
            <a @click="$emit('closeMobileMenu', $event)" href="#" title="Sluit menu"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Search from './components/Search.vue';

export default {
    props: {
        data: Object
    },
    components: {
        Search
    },
    computed: {
        device() {
            return this.$store.getters['collection/layout/getDevice'];
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see I have a computed property called "device", which is set to false or true in the default.vue layout:

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this._debounce(determineScreenSize.bind(this), 100))

    function determineScreenSize() {
        if(window.innerWidth < 1025) {
            this.$store.commit('collection/layout/setDevice', true);
        }

        if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
            this.$store.commit('collection/layout/setMobile', true);
        }

        if(window.innerWidth > 767) {
            this.$store.commit('collection/layout/setMobile', false);
        }

        if(window.innerWidth > 1024) {
            this.$store.commit('collection/layout/setDevice', false);
        }
    }
    if(this !== undefined) {
        determineScreenSize.apply(this);
    }
},
```

And of course I have this value in the Vuex store (module) with it's appropriate mutation and getter.

```
export const state = () => ({
    data: {},
    isDevice: false,
    isMobile: false
})

export default {
    getters: {
        getDevice: state => {
            console.log(state.isDevice);
            return state.isDevice
        }

        getMobile: state => {
            return state.isMobile
        }
    }

    , mutations : {
        
        setDevice( state, data ) {
            state.isDevice = data
        }

        setMobile( state, data ) {
            state.isMobile = data
        }
    }
}
```

On initial pageload everything is going as planned. If the user is on a device, it displays it and if not, it doesn't. However, as you can see on resize it changes the state.isDevice and state.isMobile properties. But the template itself doesn't get repainted by Vue/Nuxt. Is there a reason for that? Am I doing something in a completely wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the function is actually called, here's a screenshot with the VueDevtools after resizing the window a few times:

[image: Vue Dev tools]

Comment: In the screenshot, does `collection.layout` state contain what you expect?  And where is the module `namespaced`?  The commit uses namespaced syntax but the module doesn't show it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this will help but it would be better practice to declare your `determineScreenSize` function as a method in your default.vue component, then update your `mounted()` method to: `window.addEventListener('resize', this._debounce(this.determineScreenSize, 100)); this.determineScreenSize()`. Just in case your context bindings are interfering with the getter reactivity somehow.